# Beamer footcite citation appears twice if used in long caption

Tags: beamer, captions, footnotes, citing

I noticed strange behaviour of the `\footcite` command when used in captions within beamer. In the working example provided the first frame has a `\footcite` on an itemize item, this works as expected. The second frame has a `\footcite` in a caption within a table, again this works as expected. The third frame is identical to the second, except it has a caption that spans two lines (a long caption). **When the caption is pushed to the next line, as in the case of the third frame, two citations appear at the bottom of the frame when only once is expected.** Both these citations are identical, but the footmark increased (in this case #3 is no where to be found, but #4 was present in the caption).

Is there some way around this strange behaviour? I don't really want to cut my citations down so they fit on one line. I am not sure if this is some weird bug or that I am using `\footcite` inappropriately.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybibfile.bib}
@ARTICLE{authora,
  author = {A. Aaaaa},
  title = {Some article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {1-5}
}

@ARTICLE{authorb,
  author = {B. Baaaa},
  title = {Another article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {6-10}
}

@ARTICLE{authorbb,
  author = {B. Baaaa},
  title = {Another dup article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {6-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note,autocite=footnote,abbreviate=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{Beamer}
\author{Anyone}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ItemA~\footcite{authora} %This works
    \item ItemB
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{table}[!tb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline 1 & 2 \\
      \hline a & b \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This only appears once~\footcite{authorb}.}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{table}[!tb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline 1 & 2 \\
      \hline a & b \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This only appears twice because the caption spans two lines blah blah blah blah?~\footcite{authorbb}.}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footnotes and footnote citations are problematic inside captions; as a workaround, you can use `\footnotemark` inside the `\caption` and `\footcitetext{<text>}` outside the caption:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybibfile.bib}
@ARTICLE{authora,
  author = {A. Aaaaa},
  title = {Some article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {1-5}
}

@ARTICLE{authorb,
  author = {B. Baaaa},
  title = {Another article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {6-10}
}

@ARTICLE{authorbb,
  author = {B. Baaaa},
  title = {Another dup article},
  journal = {Journal of Dummy Article Names},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {99},
  pages = {6-10}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note,autocite=footnote,abbreviate=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{Beamer}
\author{Anyone}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ItemA~\footcite{authora} %This works
    \item ItemB
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline 1 & 2 \\
      \hline a & b \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This only appears once~\footnotemark.}
  \end{table}
\footcitetext{authorb}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline 1 & 2 \\
      \hline a & b \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This appears once~\footnotemark.}
  \end{table}
\footcitetext{authorbb}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As a side note, in `beamer` there's no need to use placement specifiers for floats since `beamer` internally deactivates the floating mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is here another decade later, for some reason loading the [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package seems to just fix it?

I don't know much about TeX, maybe this breaks something else...

```tex
...
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\usepackage{caption}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
...
```

Worked for my weird `enotez` thing as well.

Comment: wait this bumps the question is this bad